# Best way to programmatically layout UILabel and UIView subviews in UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: swift, ios-autolayout, uitableview

Using Swift and autolayout, what's the best way to put a label and custom view in a cell?  I want the label on the left and the view on the right.  The view could be any subclass of UIView.  One problem I'm having is sizing the label's width to fit the text.  I want the custom view to take up the remainder of the space.  I prefer to not use the visual format but instead NSLayoutConstraint():

```
func tableView(aTableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath anIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: aTableView.bounds.size.width, height: aTableView.estimatedRowHeight))

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    titleLabel.text = "some text"
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    cell.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    titleLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))


    let customView = UIView()
    cell.contentView.addSubview(customView)
    cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: titleLabel, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line:

```
customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoContraints = false
```

you might also need an additional constraint to define maybe the max size of the UILabel or the min size of the UIView.

Since you have `numberOfLines = 0`, the UILabel doesn't know exactly when to break into a new line, since there are no constraints specifying that.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Create the label and give these constraints

- horizontal spacing constraint between custom view and the label
- trailing space constraint to content view
- Top space and bottom space for the label and custom view
- Leading space for the custom view

Here the label automatically grows with the content and the custom view will occupy the remaining space.